# BibTex cannot open database file. Path is correct though, and the file name without white spaces

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

I am using BibTex for the first time. After creating references.bib with BibDesk for Mac I included in my document in TexShop:

```
\documentclass[12pt, twoside]{report}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{lipsum}


\begin{document}

ABCDEFGHIJKLMNNOPQRSTUVWXYZ.\cite{cite}

\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{/Users/chef/Desktop/Bachelor Thesis/111_AA_TeX/bibliography/references}

\end{document}
```

The typesetting follows this order: Latex / BibTex / LaTex / Latex

The references.bib is definitely in the given path. The testomatico.tex document is one folder above in /Users/chef/Desktop/Bachelor Thesis/111_AA_TeX/testomatico.tex

The references.bib looks like this:

```
@article{cite,
    address = {Department of Microbiology and Immunology, University of Michigan; csrule{\char64}umich.edu.; Department of Microbiology and Immunology, University of Michigan.; Department of Microbiology and Immunology, University of Michigan.},
    author = {Rule, Chelsea S and Patrick, Marcella and Sandkvist, Maria},
    date = {2016 Aug 23},
    date-added = {2021-06-14 16:40:59 +0200},
    date-modified = {2021-06-14 17:43:08 +0200},
    journal = {J Vis Exp},
    month = {Aug},
    number = {114},
    title = {Measuring In Vitro ATPase Activity for Enzymatic Characterization.},
    year = {2016},
    Bdsk-Url-1 = {https://doi.org/10.3791/54305}}
```

However when typesetting the second step (BibTex) I receive the following:

```
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2021)
The top-level auxiliary file: testomatico.aux
The style file: unsrt.bst
I couldn't open database file /Users/chef/Desktop/BachelorThesis/111_AA_TeX/bibliography/references.bib
---line 4 of file testomatico.aux
 : \bibdata{/Users/chef/Desktop/BachelorThesis/111_AA_TeX/bibliography/references.bib
 :                                                                                   }
I'm skipping whatever remains of this command
I found no database files---while reading file testomatico.aux
Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "cite"
(There were 2 error messages)
```

Additionally you can find main.aux here (note that it shows some other stuff going on from the document irrelevant to this problem):

```
\relax 
\citation{cite}
\bibstyle{unsrt}
\bibdata{/Users/chef/Desktop/BachelorThesis/111_AA_TeX/bibliography/references.bib}
\gdef \@abspage@last{2}
```

All the other users with this problem either gave the wrong path as an input or had a filename including white spaces. Neither is the problem for me, so I decided to post this question.

Hopefully someone can help me.

Best.

Comment: No idea why I imported lipsum.

Comment: well your path has a space. Why don't you put the bib beside your document so that you simply load it with \bibliography{references}? Or as it is one folder below why don't you use \bibliography{bibliography/references}?

Comment: Well, so I actually was more dumb than I thought. I didn't realise this also refers to folder names. Thanks a lot, it is working now!